# Unable to add reference to mvvmcross via nuget

Tags: nuget, mvvmcross

I am trying to add references to mvvmcross using nuget but I keep getting the error below.

[image]

I don't understand why it's doing this.

Thanks!

Comment: Which version of NuGet are you using? Make sure you are on the latest version 2.8

Comment: Hey Kiliman, thanks for the reply. Nuget is at version 2.8. I thought that was the problem too. So I already did an uninstall/re-install. No dice :(

Answer (score 0):

Did you try installing with the -Verbose switch from NuGet console to see what it says?

http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/using-the-package-manager-console

Comment: Yes. Somewhere along the way, MvvmCross.PortableSupport was being uninstalled. And after a successful uninstall I get an "Install failed. Rolling back..." message. ANd it just stats removing files and eventually end up with this...Install-Package : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package MvvmCross -Verbose
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], NullReferenceException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

Comment: Not sure how I can help. Try to google for 'Unable to add reference to  nuget' or 'Object reference not set to an instance of an objec nuget' I see there different results. Do you have Visual Studio Service Pack installed to the latest? Maybe try to run VisualStudio as admin?

Comment: I will do that. Thanks Andrei, I'll let you know how it turns out. Cheers!